# How to create a boundary in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

Just started making a game using sprite kit and what i need to know is how do i set up a boundary so my character stays on the screen,as in doesn't fall away due to gravity and doesn't float away when you tap the screen enough.

Comment: Andreys answer is correct. and then you can react on collisions so your object can react when colliding with border.

Answer (score 10):

Define `physicsBody` for `SKScene`:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

Described well in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW1), Listing 8-1

Comment: **Swift 4.0** self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)